# How to specify the colors and toggle labels for each category in R sunburst?

Tags: r, d3.js, donut-chart, sunburst-diagram, htmlwidgets

I can't seem to understand how `sunburst` in the `sunburstR` package handles certain paramenters, namely the vector of colors given to it and how it applies the colors towards the different categories, as well as how to show the labels for the different partitions.

Is there a logic to it, and is there a better way to manually specify which color should go with which root/leaf?

From `?sunburst` : (No idea what they mean by "supply a list with range and/or domain."

> colors
> vector of strings representing colors as hexadecimal for manual colors.
> If you want precise control of colors, supply a list with range and/or domain.
> For advanced customization, supply a JavaScript function.

Thanks!

```
sourcestatus

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  SourceStatus         count
  <chr>                <int>
1 blood-affected        4369
2 blood-unaffected      2848
3 blood-unknown            1
4 cell_line-affected    1797
5 cell_line-unaffected   151
```

Create sunburst:

```
 sunburst(sourcestatus, count = TRUE, percent= T, 
          colors = c("#6b5b95", "#feb236", "#d64161", "#ff7b25"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Colors specified simply with a list of colors:

```
colors = c("#6b5b95", "#feb236", "#d64161", "#ff7b25")
```

Will repeat those colors moving clockwise layer by layer. This ensures no adjacent leafs in the same layer have the same color (child/parent leaves can). If specifying only one color, the color is ignored and the default color palette is used.

While it is not clear how to specify colors using the domain and range on the r side of things, you can specify what color you would like each leaf to be filled with. If you have a lot of leafs you'd want to build a function to fill this data in, but here's a demonstration using a quick and dirty dataframe and a few colors:

```
library(sunburstR)

leafs <- c("base","base-child1-grandchild1","base-child1-grandchild2","base-child1","base-child2-grandchild3","base-child2","base-child3-grandchild4","base-child3-grandchild5","base-child3-grandchild6","base-child3-grandchild7","base-child3")
values <- c(200,15,10,20,55,10,120,30,30,20,10)  

# colors
colors <- c("#c994c7","#6a51a3","#807dba","#bcbddc","#74c476","#c7e9c0","#fcbba1","#fc9272","#ef3b2c","#cb181d","#99000d")
# match those colors to leaf names, matched by index
labels <- c("base","grandchild1","grandchild2","child1","child2","grandchild3","grandchild4","grandchild5","grandchild6","grandchild7","child3")

df = data.frame(v1=leafs, v2=values);

sunburst(df, 
         colors = list(range = colors, domain = labels))
```

Giving each first level child its own color scheme:

[image]

The list fed to colors contains a range of output colors and a domain of input leaf names, which allows pairing of specific colors to specific leafs.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Any idea how to toggle the labels so that they appear on each partition?

Comment: There might be a way - but the overlap would probably be pretty bad on anything very complex. Mouse over might be easier in terms of placement - from what I can see both require some custom javascript functionality (similar for both) embedded in. Adding a toggle probably complicates that a little, but not unbearably. I won't be able to take a look until later tonight, I didn't really see that part of the question to be honest. It might be best as two separate questions - as the methods for colors and labels aren't likely to share much.

Comment: @gaelgarcia, sorry for the delay - a few things came up, I'm still looking at the labels, but have run out of time for the day.

Comment: While I can add a tooltip easily - [example](https://gist.github.com/Andrew-Reid/b2ffa2b869edf3095b0a2b2f20341e3d) - the labels are a hard thing to place, and notoriously hard to place aesthetically ([example](https://codepen.io/mitel/pen/dzunp)), especially after the chart has been generated. I'll give it some more thought, but I'm not particularly hopeful for a graceful solution. A need for labels has previously been raised on sunburstr's [github page](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/sunburstR/issues/59).