# SunburstR: vector of colors

Tags: r, plot, sunburst-diagram

I've been trying to change the colors in my sunburst plot using sunburstR. I df have 3 levels (level 1 to 3 from centre) and the size. I create the plot fine just using the `sunburst(df)` but I would like for the colors in level 2 and 3 to match the color in level 1 but using different shades.

I've tried defining colors and lebels as suggested here [How to specify the colors and toggle labels for each category in R sunburst?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993198/how-to-specify-the-colors-and-toggle-labels-for-each-category-in-r-sunburst) but the best I get is:

[image]

I actually would like for subsets in level 2 and 3 to have the same level 1 (centre) color but different shades.

I hope you can help me.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need to do is add the extra two transparency characters for the hex codes.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201134/transparent-argb-hex-value#:~:text=Transparency%20is%20controlled%20by%20the,mixed%20with%20the%20background%20color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201134/transparent-argb-hex-value#:%7E:text=Transparency%20is%20controlled%20by%20the,mixed%20with%20the%20background%20color).

In R, these two extra characters fit on the end of the hex code.
For example, #c994c7 is the root color and #c994c780 has 50% transparency.